# Why is brew not compiling boost correctly?

Tags: c++, macos, boost, homebrew

I'm on Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.3, and brew install boost is not compiling boost correctly.  For example, running

```
g++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/include -x c++ -E /dev/null -include boost/version.hpp      && echo SUCCESS:
```

gives me

```
# 1 "/dev/null"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 326 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
In file included from <built-in>:326:
<command line>:1:10: fatal error: 'boost/version.hpp' file not found
#include "boost/version.hpp"
         ^
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "/dev/null" 2
```

I noticed that the directory structure obtained through Brew installing is substantially different from the one listed here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html  Maybe this doesn't affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

The command should instead be

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include -x c++ -E /dev/null -include boost/version.hpp && echo SUCCESS
```